# Not able to login through Microsoft SSO in my app

Tags: ios, iphone, mobile, single-sign-on, adfs

We are using sso(single sign on) in our webapp to login. And we have iOS app which just renders the webview of our webapp.

We are facing issue when logging to iOS app with Microsoft SSO provider. User is able to login through mobile safari browser but not through the iOS app.

UserAgent used in iOS app is "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/12.0.1 Safari/605.1.15 AppMobile";

Can someone know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you seeing a blank screen or some error message?

Comment: Are you still facing the issue ?